# What is the meaning of "out" object for box plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, outliers

Suppose this is my data set:

```
ID<- seq(1:50)
mou<-sample(c(2000, 2500, 440, 4990, 23000, 450, 3412, 4958,745,1000), 50, replace= TRUE)
calls<-sample(c(50, 51, 12, 60, 90, 888, 444, 668, 16, 89, 222,33, 243, 239, 333, 645,23, 50,555), 50, replace= TRUE)
rev<- sample(c(100, 345, 758, 44, 58, 334, 50000, 888, 205, 940,298, 754), 50, replace= TRUE)
dt<- data.frame(mou, calls, rev)
```

I did the box plot for calls and while analyzing it, I saw the following objects for the boxplot.

```
x<-boxplot(dt$calls)
names(x)
> names(x)
[1] "stats" "n"     "conf"  "out"   "group" "names"
```

Looking at the output for x$stats, I figured  that stats object gives me the lower whisker the lower hinge, the median, the the upper hinge and the upper whisker for each group. But i am little bit confused what the object "out" really mean? Does this signify the outlier values or something else? 
The out object for my boxplot gives the following results:

```
> x$out
[1]   555 10000   555   555   555   555   555 10000
```

Comment: Consider asking this kind of question at other communities like [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you: "The values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes of the whiskers"

Take a look at [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html) for more insight.